# Cannot read from a file opened in read/write/append mode

Tags: perl

Here is my code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(INFILE,"<File1")    or die "Can't open the file";
open(OUTFILE,"+>>File2") or die "Can't open the file";

while(<INFILE>) {
   print OUTFILE "$_";
}

while(<OUTFILE>) {
   print "$_\n"; 
}
```

Am trying to move the contents of File1 to File2 which is created in read,write and append mode. The problem here is I have my File2 created with File1 contents, but the `print` statement inside the `while(<OUTFILE>) {}` is not printing the contents of File2. 
Anyone help me understand what is wrong here!(I might be making a silly mistake)

Answer (score 5):

After your first `while` loop, you are at the end of the `OUTFILE`.  So, the second `while` loop is never really executed.  Use [seek](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) before you read `OUTFILE`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open(INFILE,"<File1")or die "Can't open the file";
open(OUTFILE,"+>>File2")or die "Can't open the file";
while(<INFILE>)
{
print OUTFILE "$_";
}

seek OUTFILE, 0, 0;

while(<OUTFILE>)
{
    print "$_\n"; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the cursor back to the start of OUTFILE:

```
seek OUTFILE, 0, 0;
```